# How does converting css pixels to device pixels work for Iphones?

Tags: css

Xiaomi Redmi 4A that has a resolution: 1280 X 720 (in device pixels) and 640 x 360 (in CSS pixels). CSS pixel-ratio is 2. To convert CSS pixels to Device pixels I multiply CSS pixels by CSS pixel-ratio, so 640*2 X 360*2 = 1280 X 720. At this moment everything is as I expect it to work

Iphone 8 Plus has a resolution 1920×1080 (In device pixels) and 732 X 414 (in CSS pixels). CSS pixel-ratio is 3. When I do the same multiplication that I did above for Redmi 4A, I don't get the expected result, so 732*3 X 414*3 doesn't equal to 1920×1080

Could you explain what is wrong?

Comment: I suppose it's because the real ratio is around 2.6:1, but that's being rounded up to the integer value 3.

Comment: @kshetline Thanks for the reply! I thought about it, but can't find any reasonable explanation of why it's rounded

Comment: According to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html), the 8 Plus has a native scale factor/CSS pixel ratio of 2.608.

Comment: @ajm Thanks. What is the reason of converting it to an integer?

Comment: @RomanRoman If I had to guess its that humans are lazy and math is much easier when using whole numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS screen are expressed in terms of points (pt.) which is used as a unit of measurement across all iOS designs. 1 point is always 1 point and is an abstract unit, only having meaning when referenced in relation to other points.

You can get the css screen size by using Native scale given by Apple for every device. Refer this link:

For different iPhone models refer the dimension sheet below for sizes in pt.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html

```
px = pt. x (Native scale)
```

Let see how native scale is derived taking into special case of iPhone 8 and 8+ models.

As per Apple the value of

```
1pt = 
      1 px at 163 dpi (1px x 1px = 1 pt) (Render @ 1x)
      4 px at 326 dpi (2px x 2px = 1 pt) (Render @ 2x)
      9 px at 489 dpi (3px x 3px = 1 pt) (Render @ 3x)
      ...
```

To calculate px from point use the following formula

```
px = (pt * DPI)/163
```

Considering case for iPhone 8

```
DPI: 326, Screen Size: 325pt x 667pt

L: (325 * 326)/163 = 650px
H: (667 * 326)/163 = 1334px
```

Making css screen as 650px x 1334px, where UI will be rendered are 2x and native scale @ 2.0

Considering case for iPhone 8 plus

```
DPI: 401, Screen Size: 414pt x 736pt

L: (414 * 401)/163 = 1018.5px
H: (736 * 401)/163 = 1810.6px

Making screen as 1018.5px x 1810.6px
```

Now it is not possible to render screen @ 2.46x as we cannot have a grid for 2.46px x 2.46px (Pixel is absolute unit not divisible) Getting to nearest whole number the screen is rendered are 3x. The native scale of iPhone 8+ is 2.608, which makes screen size as

```
L: 414 * 2.608 = 1080px
H: 736 * 2.608 = 1920px
```

This is how native scale factor is derived for devices to render UI at 1x, 2x or 3x and its relation with sizes and pixels.